# AngularJS sending only the default values of model to the API controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-controller

I am creating a Single Page Application using ASP.NET Web API and AngularJS.
The problem is that when I post data from AngularJS controller to API controller, the object is getting passed but all the values of different properties are not those which were assigned but default values.

Model is defined as follows:

```
 public class Expense
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

This is the value of object which I passed from AngularJS controller, which I see in the AngularJS JavaScript file breakpoint,

```
"{"ID":1,"Description":"test","Amount":1000}"

 $http.post("/Expenses/Create",  $scope.expense);
```

And this is what it reaches to the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]        
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public IActionResult Create(Expense expenses)`

{"ID":0,"Description":null,"Amount":0}"
```

Comment: this probably means that the data is not correctly formatted, your request reaches the server but with no data or invalid data

Comment: what can be done to correctly format the data?